# How to check a python list whether it contains the element I have just inserted

Tags: python

I want to write a txt file using python, this file contains many elements and should be continuous updated. I should check whether it contains the element before I insert. The problem is here:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'a+')
content = list(f)
f.write('905771\n')
if '905771\n' in content:
    print 'ok'
else:
    print 'no'
f.close()
```

It will return 'no',but I inserted it,the element may be in the buffer pool. If I close the file immediately after `f.write('905771\n')`,there will be many `open` and `close` in this program as there are many elements. So how can I check the list whether it contains the element I have just inserted? Thanks very much.

Comment: You didn't update `content` after you did the write.

Comment: @JohnColeman, yes you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to switch these two lines:

```
content = list(f)
f.write('905771\n')
```

Otherwise you're reading checking against the content of the file before you inserted the new element.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're writing the data (905771\n) to file `f` but not updating list `content`.

```
f = open('test.txt', 'a+')
content = list(f)
f.write('905771\n')
content.append('905771\n')   #add data to content to update list
if '905771\n' in content:
    print 'ok'
else:
    print 'no'
f.close()
```

Or like [andreas-hofmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5719329/andreas-hofmann) stated you can first write to file `f` and then create the list `content` and check it:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'a+')
f.write('905771\n')
content = list(f)
if '905771\n' in content:
    print 'ok'
else:
    print 'no'
f.close()
```

Comment: yes, in this way I should write the list to the txt file at the end, but this program may be interrupted at any time. So if it is interrupted, I should make a fresh start. Any way, this is a kind of choice, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
    alldata = f.read()

if "searchPhrase" in alldata:
    print("Ok")
else:
    print("no")
```

Just red it and check if searchPhrase is in file.